# Freeze or pause iPhone camera image

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-sdk-3.1, iphone-sdk-3.1.2

On iPhone's built-in Camera application (OS 3.1), touching the shutter button shows an iris animation, then displays the image that was taken for a second or so before animating it away.

Is anyone aware of a simple way to get this "brief pause" activity?  Or do I have to resort to manually adding the image as part of my custom cameraOverlayView?

Bonus points for the iris animation too (without interfering with said custom overlay).

Comment: The iris animation is an undocumented built-in transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I ended up using `UIGetScreenImage()` (which is now [officially blessed for use by Apple](https://devforums.apple.com/message/149553#149553)) and pushing that image to a previously hidden UIImageView.

Meh.

Answer (score 0):

did you try releasing the ImagePickerController after your code be done?